# Shell escape after PDF is finished and closed?

Tags: compiling, shell-escape, hooks

I like to escape to the shell using `\write18` at the very end of the compilation after the PDF file got completely written and was closed, so that I can use it as part the shell command. Is this somehow possible or does TeX simply closed the PDF at the very last thing? Placing it direct before `\end{document}` or in `\AtEndDocument` doesn't help (unsurprisingly). 
AFAIK `\write`s are actually *whatsit* objects and would be normally be part of the document. So I don't have much hopes.

#### Background

This is used for automatic PDF-to-PNG conversion as a new feature of `standalone`. At the moment I do this in the preamble in the second run when the old PDF did not yet got opened. This works fine, but I would like to avoid the need to compile standalone diagrams twice.

Comment: Is there a way to `write18` in the preamble a shell command that "waits until compilation ends and then does something"? That would be a way around it?

Comment: @Seamus: Nice idea. I will look into it. However this might be platform dependent :-(

Comment: almost certainly, but all the cool kids use unix, so I wouldn't worry about windows compatibility...

Comment: @Seamus: I will cite you in the package manual then :-)

Comment: @Seamus: I think I need the process ID of the LaTeX compiler. It's however not the parent ID which is the shell which got started...

Comment: Can't you do something like `$(pidof latex)` ? I can't remember exactly, but there's a way to get the pid of a process with a particular name...

Comment: @Seamus: This would return all `latex` processes. There could still be some around, e.g. when one is interrupted due to an error. Happens to me all the time.

Comment: With `luatex`, the callback `stop_run` (p.46 of the documentation) might help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do something like this (based on an idea of Ulrich Diez):

```
\documentclass{article}

\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
  \immediate\write18{%
    pdfLaTeX --jobname="\jobname"
    \gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname
  }%
  \immediate\write18{%
    LaTeX --jobname="\jobname"
    \gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname
  }%
   \immediate\write18{dvips \jobname}
   \expandafter\stop
\fi

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

I'm not quite sure if it a very good idea to use \jobname in the subprocesses, it seems to work but \jobname1 or something like this is perhaps safer.

Btw: I'm one of uncool kids who uses windows.

Comment: Ok, basically I already use the first part of it, just the `\stop` here is new. Thanks, I didn't know it before. Running the same compiler internally and then the conversion script, then stop the main process before it touches the PDF. This should work. One drawback is that you need full shell escape. The conversion script alone would only required restricted shell escape and its name added to the list. This is my config, but the normal usage will be using full shell escape anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out the compiler which got used? I used `\ifpdf pdf\fi latex` so far.

Comment: I'm not sure I would be happy if some package allowed itself to do such things in my document :-)

Comment: @Martin: http://ctan.org/pkg/iftex

Comment: @Andrey: It's not a package but a class which does this only if the user request it to do so.

Comment: @Andrey: this works only if you call pdflatex with the option `--shell-escape` (or `--enable-write18`) and you can disable the restricted shell escape with `--disable-write18`. So it is up to you to allow the package to do such things.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to handle this. I'm accepting it now, because there seems to be no real way to get such a hook.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible; the only place where to hook is `\end`; let's see an example in LaTeX:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@@@@end\@@end
\def\@@end{\immediate\write18{ls -l \jobname.pdf}\@@@@end}
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Compiling it gives on standard output

```
-rw-r--r--  1 staff  159 Jul 13 17:50 shellatend.pdf
```

but `ls -l shellatend.pdf` after compilation has ended gives

```
-rw-r--r--  1 staff  10200 Jul 13 17:50 shellatend.pdf
```

So the PDF file has not yet been written out completely.

Putting the shell command after `\@@@@end` does nothing (obviously).

Comment: That's what I thought. I just hoped that there was some thing or dirty trick which allowed that and I simply didn't now yet.

Answer (score 5):

A non-portable solution, which appears to work with TeXLive 2011's `pdflatex --shell-escape` run in the `sh` shell (hence most likely any shell based on `sh`) is to detach the process that you want to run after the end of the `pdflatex` run. To ensure that things happen after the run has really ended, I used

```
sleep 3&&\ 
  nohup cp \jobname.pdf \jobname.copy\ 
  2>/dev/null
```

(without the newline continuations). The first instruction waits 3 seconds for the end of the run (that number is arbitrary), with `&&` detaching it (not sure how that works exactly). Then `cp \jobname.pdf \jobname.copy` copied the result pdf file; you could replace by the `convert` utility, or any other actual conversion program. I'm not quite sure why `nohup` is needed for that but not for the `sleep` command, but that prevents the call to `cp` to abort when the parent process (`pdflatex`) ends. The final step is to redirect errors to `2>/dev/null`, because for some reason `nohup` produces an error (that's probably a bad sign, to investigate).

Of course, to use this in a package for general consumption, you'd need to figure out similar solutions for Windows and Mac, I guess, and figure out whether this covers all other OSes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1-10]

\section{Bar}
\lipsum[11-20]

\immediate\write18{ls -la \jobname.*}
\immediate\write18
  {sleep 3&&nohup cp "\jobname.pdf" "\jobname.copy" 2>/dev/null&}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the message `appending output to nohup.out` which is not an error: since the process is detached from the terminal there must be an output channel different from the terminal. If you say `1>/dev/null` you get neither the message nor the `nohup.out` file. But, of course, this depends on what commands are needed. It work on Mac OS X, by the way.

Comment: @egreg I suppose the easiest is to redirect both 1 and 2. Not sure why that's different between `sh` and your shell.