# How can I test if a document is being compiled by XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, conditionals

Is there a way to programatically test whether the current document is being compiled by (pdf)LaTeX or XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\else
   \usepackage{tgtermes}
\fi
```

There's also **ifluatex**. These packages define also `\RequireXeTeX` and `\RequireLuaTeX` respectively, that throw an error if the corresponding engine is not used.

As Martin remarks, the **iftex** package does the work of both defining different conditionals. This package is automatically loaded with **bidi**.

Comment: There is also the general [`iftex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/iftex) package: "which works both for Plain TeX and for LaTeX, defines the `\ifPDFTeX`, `\ifXeTeX`, and `\ifLuaTeX` conditionals for testing which engine is being used for typesetting.

The package also provides the `\RequirePDFTeX`, `\RequireXeTeX`, and `\RequireLuaTeX` commands which throw an error if pdfTeX, XeTeX or LuaTeX (respectively) is not the engine in use." (Thanks goes to [Andrey Vihrov](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22982/22999#comment-44933) for pointing this out to me recently)

Comment: @egreg: This only works if we assume there are only two engines (xetex and pdftex).

Comment: Very similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13175/8666