# Why doesn't standalone accept my build={} package option?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, xetex, standalone

I frequently use standalone to incorporate tikz images in my documents. I have some really large `tikz` plots which I would like to include in my beamer presentation, but I am getting "Tex capacity exceeded" errors. First I tried unsuccessfully to "externalize" my `tikz` plot using `standalone` and the `external` library, but after reading [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23587/why-does-tikz-neither-draw-nor-externalize-my-picture), I have abandoned that effort and have been trying to accomplish the same thing just with `standalone`.

I use `xelatex` exclusively and I want `standalone` to do this also. The manual says I can set the LaTeX compiler in the package options:

> build={build options}
>
> This option allows to set the options used for
>   building images from standalone files. See section 5.4, especially
>   Table 3 for further details.

When I try to do this, though, like this:

```
\usepackage[build={latex=xelatex}]{standalone}
```

I get this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `build' for package `standalone'.
```

This is a complete mystery to me, as I have tried other package options taken from the same section of the manual in my MWE (such as `obeyclassoptions`) and it has built successfully. Note that even if the syntax for the definition is incorrect, it's telling me that it doesn't recognize `build` in the first place. (Please correct my syntax if it is wrong.)

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[build={latex=xelatex}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A slide}
Bla and bla.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Another slide}
\input{testplot.tex}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the code for `testplot.tex`, taken from the `pgfplots` manual:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
]
\addplot {x^2 - x +4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Keep in mind that my ultimate goal is to include my giant `tikz` plot and not have XeLaTeX quit on me due to insufficient memory, so please let me know if this is not possible with `standalone`. Doing it with `external` alone didn't work, though. The compile dies without errors but without giving me a readable document, either.

Comment: I would compile the image `testplot.tex` on its own and generate a stand-alone PDF as output. Then use `\includegraphics[..]{testplot}` inside your [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) presentation. This way the two processes are separate and inclusion should be straight forward.

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issue/7/build-key-broken) about this bug, at the standalone repository.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It works for me with xelatex if I just remove the offending option

```
\usepackage[]{standalone}
```

Comment: Are you sure the plot was compiled with xelatex? Here's what my logs are telling me: xelatex is compiling the main document, but the standalone docs are being compiled with pdflatex.

Comment: @StephenBosch actually the logs suggest it's all run in one pass with no internal job at all What do you see in your log?

Comment: hrm, it appears that I am no longer able to reproduce this pdflatex phenomenon. Still, I would like to know why the build={} option to standalone isn't working.

Comment: @StephenBosch I don't see a build option in the source (although I didn't look too hard) but it is in the doc (and I get the same error) ping Martin:-)

Comment: I figured you might say that :)