# Can the standalone document type be made compatible with tikzexternalize?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, tikz-external

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] at (2, 3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] at (2, 3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Yields

> ! Missing }
>   inserted.

Something is wrong with standalone when used with tikzexternalize.  Can this be made to work?

Comment: it seems not: [Why does tikz neither draw nor externalize my picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23587)

Comment: @cmhughes: can standalone produce a pdf for each tikzpicture?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do exactly? As I understand it, `standalone` produces 1-out-for-1-in. But can't you just use two source files? Or use `externalize` *rather than* `standalone`?

Comment: @cfr: I generate a latex file with all of my images.  I want them all to be compiled to individual pdfs that I can then include in my real latex file.  This works with tikzexternal and standalone if I don't give standalone the tikz option.  With that option, standalone puts each tikzpicture on a separate page, which is nice for viewing.

Comment: I still don't see why you can't have each image in a separate file. Then your viewing file can use `standalone` as a package just as your main file does.

Comment: @cfr Can you explain what you mean?  My "main file" uses memoir.  My generated file uses "standalone" because memoir was letting figures extend out of the page.

Comment: So you just need a script to split the generated file into separate files. (If you can't change the generation to use separate files.) Or use `externalize` and include the images back into a file for viewing. (But splitting is probably more flexible if the number of generated images might change.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13099/discussion-between-neil-g-and-cfr)

Comment: Sorry. The system doesn't recognise me on Chat or Meta. I can read but I can't write. But that probably doesn't matter since probably somebody else there will have a brighter idea;)

Comment: @NeilG: When you use `tikz` as option, `standalone` produces a pdf file with as much pages as `tikzpicture`. You can use `\includegraphics[page=#]{xxx}` to include one of them. Better explained at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29820/how-can-i-generate-just-pgf-tikz-images-not-placed-a-whole-page-or-slide/29875#29875

Comment: @ignasi: Thanks, yes, that definitely works.  Is it true that tikzexternal won't rebuild graphics that haven't changed?  Plus referencing graphics by page number rather than by name means that if I insert a graphic, I'll have to redo all of the page references.

Comment: @NeilG Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31489/1952) help?

Comment: @Ignasi: Yes, that solves the referencing problem.  tikzexternal is still nice for its conditional rebuild, I think.

Comment: Old stuff, but @NeilG Could you offer your answer or is it a duplicat to the linked questions of Ignasi?