# Conditional naming of the output PDF file

Tags: luatex, output, latex-base, jobname

My target is to have an output `Solved Exam.pdf` when `\ifSolution` is true, and `The Exam.pdf` when `\ifSolution` is false.

However, I don't know if [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252346/2288) is relevant here to change the `\jobname` and thus all the output files since it only affects the name of the `aux` file.

P.S. I am using `lualatex` to compile.

```
\newif\ifSolution

\ifSolution
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252346/2288
    \edef\TeXjobname{\jobname}
    \edef\jobname{\detokenize{Solved Exam}}% <<< the output file is not "Solved Exam.pdf"
    \documentclass[answers]{exam}
\else
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252346/2288
    \edef\TeXjobname{\jobname}
    \edef\jobname{\detokenize{Exam}}% <<< the output file is not "Exam.pdf"
    \documentclass{exam}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question a question
    \begin{solution}
        the solution
    \end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could setting the values at compilation time help? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152716/passing-a-lot-of-parameters-to-a-file-at-compilation-time

Comment: [How to influence the name of the pdf file created with pdfLaTeX (from within the source code)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19182/82917). I think what you are trying to do is simply not possible. I've always used bash scripts for that.

Comment: @campa would you please provide an answer to my question with such approach?

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure this is really in topic here. In fact my scripts always run the file twice to generate both versions; and they are based on a class I've written, so they look for an optional argument to `\documentclass`.

Comment: @campa I am working on Win 10. So, if you have some CMD script to share and apply to my question, I would be grateful.

Comment: Sorry, Linux scripts. But I can give it a shot. However now I'm on smartphone, so it'll take a while...

Comment: LuaTeX has a `finish_pdffile` [callback](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Callbacks). Maybe you can rename the output with Lua callback. It could be as simple as `os.rename(tex.jobname..".pdf", "new_name.pdf")`.

Comment: @AlanXiang I don't know how to do it. If you are willing to provide a relevant answer to my question, I would be grateful.

Comment: @Diaa I just did some research and realized it is impossible for this approach to work (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55775/possible-to-run-lua-script-from-lualatex-after-main-compilation-has-been-done). You could either try to see if redefining `\jobname` is possible, or try to wrap `lualatex` call around with other tools. One way I can think of is that you can write the value of `\ifSolution` to an external file and have another program inspect it and rename (copy) the output of LuaTeX.

Comment: @AlanXiang I can do it by calling a `CMD` file by texstudio that has `texfot lualatex -jobname="[Exam] <file name>" -synctex=1  -interaction=nonstopmode "\AtBeginDocument{\printanswersfalse}\input{<file name>}"`. However, I am not sure about if possible by the document itself without external help.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using TeXStudio on Windows. This is what I would do.

1. Save the following file to `compile.cmd` in project folder. **A VERY IMPORTANT REMINDER: BACK UP NECESSARY FILES BEFORE COMPILING YOUR DOCUMENT!** This script will automatically delete "Solved Exam.pdf" and "The Exam.pdf" before compiling your TeX document. Make sure you back everything up!

```cmd
@echo off
echo cleaning old pdf files
del /Q "Solved Exam.pdf" "The Exam.pdf"

echo compiling new pdf file
lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %1.tex

echo reading file mode
set filename="%1-mode.txt"
echo reading %filename%
set /p mode=<%filename%
echo the output indicates %mode% mode

IF "%mode%" EQU "exam" (
  copy %1.pdf "The Exam.pdf"
  echo output copied to "The Exam.pdf"
)
IF "%mode%" EQU "solution" (
  copy %1.pdf "Solved Exam.pdf"
  echo output copied to "Solved Exam.pdf"
)
```

2. In TeXStudio, open settings page and make sure "Show Advanced Options" check box is ticked. In the "Build" tab, add a user command that writes `cmd /c compile.cmd %`.
3. Restructure your document as follows. What I did is basically write the value of `\ifSolution` to `\jobname-mode.txt`. The `cmd` script will read this information and behave accordingly.

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifSolution

\ExplSyntaxOn

\AtEndDocument{
    \iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {\jobname-mode.txt}
    \ifSolution
        \iow_now:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {solution}
    \else
        \iow_now:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {exam}
    \fi
    \iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\Solutionfalse

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question a question
    \begin{solution}
        the solution
    \end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

4. Now you can compile the document by either clicking the menu item Tools->User-><YOUR COMMAND NAME> or using its corresponding hotkey.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think you miss something here. When I set `\Solutiontrue` I need the condition `\printanswerstrue` to be set in `\AtBeginDocument` to print the solution and vice versa for the exam mode.So, my program flow should be (1) check the state of `\Solution` (2) based on the mode, compile by `lualatex -jobname="[Exam] <\jobname>" -synctex=1  -interaction=nonstopmode "\AtBeginDocument{\printanswersfalse}\input{<\jobname>}"` **or** `lualatex -jobname="[Solution] <\jobname>" -synctex=1  -interaction=nonstopmode "\AtBeginDocument{\printanswerstrue}\input{<\jobname>}"`