# Standalone package advanced conversion options inside LaTeX source file

Tags: conversion, standalone

I want to use the conversion options of the `standalone` package to produce a PNG image file from a LaTeX source file. The package documentation lists two tables with options for conversion. The *normal* options are usable inside the `convert` class options, the *advanced* options are usable inside ... that's the question now. From the documentation examples and experiments I know that they are usable within a `standalone.cfg` file. But, my question is, if I could use them inside my source files directly somehow.

Here is a MWE of something I tried:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=600,size=400x400,outext=.png},crop,border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% The following options are ignored at this place.
% It works if this is put inside a 'standalone.cfg' file
\standaloneconfig{convert={command={\convertexe\space -density \density\space
  \infile\space
  \ifx\size\empty\else -resize \size\fi\space
  -quality 100\space
  -define png:format=png32\space
  -define png:compression-filter=4\space
  \outfile}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shadedraw [shading=ball] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- Putting the options inside the `\standaloneconfig` macro of the given MWE is ignored.
- Putting the options inside the class options (I tried several things) leads to compilation errors.

Is there a solution where and how to put the options inside my source file or am I forced to use the `standalone.cfg` file? I would consider to have all options in one file a very desirable feature. Maybe, I'm just applying things wrong?

**Update:**
Since nobody answered or commented my question the last two days, I guess it's not possible to use the advanced conversion options inside the source file (?). I would appreciate any comment ... can't imagine nobody tried this before ...

Comment: I just guess @MartinScharrer is kind of busy these days. I am pretty sure he will provide a definite answer, eventually.

Comment: @Daniel @MartinScharrer If it is not possible with the current version of `standalone`, I would like to file it as *feature request* :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, is only possible if you set it within "standalone.cfg" not within the document, however, is more like using:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=600,size=400x400,outext=.png},crop,border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{standalone.cfg}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesFile{standalone.cfg}[2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalone' class]%
% The following options are ignored at this place.
% It works if this is put inside a 'standalone.cfg' file
    \standaloneconfig{convert={command={\convertexe\space -density \density\space
      \infile\space
      \ifx\size\empty\else -resize \size\fi\space
      -quality 100\space
      -define png:format=png32\space
      -define png:compression-filter=4\space
      \outfile}}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bashful}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shadedraw [shading=ball] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the log :

```
 runsystem(convert -density 600 uno.pdf -resize 400x400 -quality 100 -define png
:format=png32 -define png:compression-filter=4 uno.png)...executed.
```

or

```
mogrify -resize 400x400 -quality 100  -define png:format=png32 -define png:compression-filter=4 -format png *.png
```

after compiled document (mogrify prserve name of the image files :). regards

Comment: I had hoped for a solution with `standalone` directly but your approach gives a good sideway solution. Nevertheless, in the meantime I found a more direct way here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22982/shell-escape-after-pdf-is-finished-and-closed  This seems to be the method `standalone` uses. I tested it and it works.

Comment: If I agree, but converting images is not like latex, I think it is good to subdivide tasks, so there is no need to compile again and again document to obtain the desired image is only done once and then play with mogrify (or convert) until you need. If you use an IDE is easy to create a profile for this, so the (and latex) system does not become overloaded in a single process.

Comment: A couple of queries for you:
Does using windows or linux?, Have installed GS or pdftk? and Have a recent version perl? then you might like this (in this beta version) https://www.dropbox.com/s/jg0e6pezrxiahuu/ltximage.zip

Comment: I'm using Windows and I do not have pdftk (I think...) or perl (I'm sure). Nevertheless, thank you for your help. Now, I use the (La)-TeX-only solution of Ulrike Fischer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22982/shell-escape-after-pdf-is-finished-and-closed which works very good.